# How do I add additional source directories to maven to generate javadoc?

Tags: java, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin

I used this in my pom.xml to recognize the second source directory I have in my project:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/java-extra/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But generating javadoc fails saying it can't find the classes in the `java-extra` directory.  How can I make maven javadoc see the second directory?

Comment: First question: Why do you have define supplemental directories with java code?

Comment: Simple answer: because I can. Better answer: separation of concerns, even though that's not really accurate. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 2):

There is a sourcepath parameter for maven-javadoc-plugin. There you provide list of your source folders, separated by `:` or `;`. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#sourcepath

For example:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourcepath>src/main/java;${defines.dir}</sourcepath>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```